# How to make MVC 4 interactive search box?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to create a search for my website that loads the results as the user types into the search box, much like Google populates the search results as you type.  I am not talking about an Auto-Complete.

Any ideas about how to implement this in MVC 4 (with or without jquery)?

BTW here is the article I tried, doesn't seem to work (I might be messing it up).  When I used the method from the article my search box kept being cleared.

[Interactive Search with jquery and ASP.Net MVC](http://geekswithblogs.net/DougLampe/archive/2010/12/21/simple-interactive-search-with-jquery-and-asp.net-mvc.aspx)

EDIT:

progrAmmar had the right approach.  This is how I implemented it for now:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SearchOrders", new AjaxOptions{ UpdateTargetId = 
"searchResults", OnSuccess = "checkSearchChanged" }))
{
      <strong>Search:</strong>  @Html.TextBox("Search", null, new { @class= 
      "wide", @onkeyup = "javascript:SearchResults(this.value)" })<input 
      id="submit" type="submit" value="Search" />
}

<div id="searchResults"></div>

<script>
function SearchResults(search) {
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Orders/Search/",
        data: { ordid: search },
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#searchResults").html(data);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert("error has occurred: " + response);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Now I have a search page that populates as the user types into the search box and filters down to the order number he/she types in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty simple,
You can create a partial view for the search results and call the action on either `change()` or `keyup()` function of the textbox (via Ajax call obviously).

Comment: Now I feel foolish...I didn't think of change() and that is the obvious one now that you mention it.  And didn't even consider keyup()!

Comment: `keyup` function will be better suited as sometimes `change` may not fire until you have actually moved focus off of the textbox.

Comment: awesome!  I am trying it out right now!

Comment: It worked as expected!  Thank you so much for your help!